# Generate Unique Object ID

Tags: java, class, object, uniqueidentifier

I'm trying to generate a new unique identifier for each object in a class, without using a `static nextID` field to just increment. Using that will create complications when unloading and unloading the program.

I came up with a solution to loop through the objects in a static method checking them all but for some unknown reason to me, it won't exit the while-loop.

I have been testing it in ideone.com [here](http://ideone.com/Huf74q) trying to create 5 objects to begin with, though it won't even create one.

Without having to go to the link to view the whole testing code, below is the method I'm using.

```
public static int newRandomID() {
    int randomID = 0;
    boolean notUnique = true;

    while (notUnique) {
        randomID = (int) (Math.random() * 999999 + 1);
        for (Example e : examples) {
            if (e.ID == randomID) {
                notUnique = true;
                break;
            }
            notUnique = false;
        }
    }
    return randomID;
}
```

Have I just made a stupid mistake that I'm too blind to see, or is there a reason that this isn't working?

Comment: A couple of general pointers: 1) Don't make names more complicated than they need to be. Change `notUnique` to just `unique` and use `!unique` where you mean "not `unique`". 2) Use `java.util.Random` to generate an integer with an upper limit. 3) Put the containment logic in a separate method. Your mistake will be clear and your program can be expressed as `while (idExisists(randomID)) randomID = rnd.nextInt(99999);`.

Answer (score 5):

If all you need is a unique identifier (that need not be sequential) and it dosn't have to be an integer, have a look at [`java.util.UUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)

Comment: Maybe because the question is `is there a reason that this isn't working?`

Comment: so I addressed the bigger issue of "I'm trying to generate a new unique identifier for each object" in a beter way....

Answer (score 0):

your `notUnique` is bit confusing and i think you are doing it wrong in here

```
if (e.ID == randomID) {
            notUnique = true;
            break;
}
```

you dont need to break the statement if the `id` exists. i changed you code may be this helps.

```
    int randomID = 0;
    boolean ContinueLoop = true;

    while (ContinueLoop) {
        randomID = (int) (Math.random() * 999999 + 1);
        boolean exist = false;
        for (Example e : examples) {
            if (e.ID == randomID) {
                exist = true;
            }else{
                exist = false;
                break;  
            }

        }

        if(exist==false){
            ContinueLoop = false;
        }else{
            ContinueLoop = true;
        }

    }
    return randomID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried to execute your code (from the link you sent):
After you created and printed 50 new ids, I tried to generate 150,000 more:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 150000; i++)
        new Example();
```

and... it works perfectly fine! Just took it a minute or so (which makes sense).
If I try to create only 15,000 records it works in less than a second.

Which leads me to the conclusion that miss rate is exponentially high and starts to be unbearable once you reach 15% of the ids capacity.

Don't continue with this solution. 
Use a different approach such as a stored sequential number (if you store the records). If you don't store the records, I don't see a reason why not to use a static int variable.